# remove unwanted spacing in Action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

I got a problem with action bar tab spacing.Below I am showing the screenshot of action bar tabs.

[image]

Below I am posted the codes relevant to this issue.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText("Tab1")
                    .setTabListener(
                            new TabListener(this, Home.class.getName()));
            View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
            tabView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_shape); // set custom color
            tab.setCustomView(tabView);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

**drawable/gradient_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0078a5" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#00adee"
        android:startColor="#0078a5" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="25dp" />

</shape>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    </style>

</resources>
```

**values-v11/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>

</resources>
```

**values-v14/styles.xml:**

```
 <resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="15"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.smart.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I need to remove the unwanted spacing between the tabs.The Tabs have to get merge one by one.And also the Action bar tab name wasn't displayed.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this in **values/styles.xml** solved my problem:

```
<resources>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabBar">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Then in **Manifest**:

I set a theme like this `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"` in `application` element.